# My .py works, but my .exe doesn't

Tags: python, windows, py2exe, win32com

I'm converting a Python file to an `.exe` using py2exe like so:

```
 from distutils.core import setup
 import py2exe, sys, os

 sys.argv.append('py2exe')

 setup(
     options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True}},
     windows = [{'script': "myfile.py"}],
     zipfile = None,
 )
```

The `.py` file works just fine, but when I create the `.exe`, I get this message:

> 3 missing Modules
>
> ?pywin types                     imported from -
>
> ?win32api                        imported from platform, win32evtlogutil
>
> ?win32com                        imported from **SCRIPT**

And when I run the `.exe`, I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "archiveFiles.py", line 83, in
>
> File "archiveFiles.py", line 5, in putItIn
>
> ImportError: No module named 'win32com'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "archiveFiles.py", line 83, in
>
> putItIn()
>
> File "archiveFiles.py", line 5, in doThatStuff
>
> import win32com.client as win32
>
> ImportError: No module named 'win32com'

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might have to explicitly state that `win32com` must be included in your `py2exe` file.

Comment: how do you suggest I do that? Sorry, new to python

Comment: Does this help any?  http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndWin32com